# Short story collection with a story about alien that dies from bandage-poisoning when in care of a village doctor

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Around 20 years ago I had a smallish book that was a collection of sci-fi short stories, and I can't find what book this was. It may have been a book targeted at youth rather than adults.

The only story I remember was about an alien that crash-lands in some rural area on contemporary Earth and sustains some injuries. The narrator gets the local doctor to come and bandage the alien, but the bandages are not pure cotton(or whatever bandages are made of), and laced with antiseptic(?) instead (as doctors bandages regularly are?). The alien then dies from antiseptic-poisoning while the government and scientists are still on their way.
The narrator then rants in frustration about inequality on Earth, where you have wondrous technological advancements and just some distance away seemingly medieval conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a nice description of *Rescue Operation* by Harry Harrison; it has been [anthologised many times](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55380).

The narrator is an educated man on holiday:

> “The diver, the one who stays with the widow Korenc, he will know what
> to do. His name is Kukovic and Petar said that he is a doctor of
> science from the university in Ljubljana.”

The alien is brought back to town, and when the spacesuit is opened its injuries are found:

> There was a sudden welling of blue liquid from the injured leg. Joze
> had a quick glimpse of green flesh, strange organs, then he spun
> about.

The doctor uses a medicated dressing:

> “You fool! You incredible fool!” he shouted. “These compresses you
> used—they’re impregnated with sulfanilamide.”

The narrator laments the death of the alien and the destruction of a book it had with it:

> “Why here?” he asked. “Of all places in the world why here? A few more
> degrees to the west and the creature would have come down near Trieste
> with surgeons, hospitals, modern facilities. Or, if it had just stayed
> on its course a little longer, it could have seen the lights, and
> would have landed at Rijeka. Something could have been done. But why
> here?” He surged to his feet, shaking his fist at nothing—and at
> everything. “Here, in this superstition-ridden, simpleminded backwater
> of the world! What kind of world do we live in where there is a
> five-million-volt electron accelerator not a hundred miles from
> primitive stupidity? That this creature should come so far, come so
> close … why, why?”

Comment: @Michael Thanks, especially for the link to the anthologies. I found the book - it was [Constellations](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?290096) . It includes another cool [story](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56229) about survival after Earth was torn away by a passing brown dwarf, after which the atmosphere freezes and a family survives by subliming the frozen air over a fire :-D